# Bootstrap navigation toggle and column stack?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm taking online course to learn bootstrap but the instructor kind of skipped over some stuff. How does bootstrap know to stack columns at a certain screen size when I didn't put it in the code? Is this just a part of the link rel (stylesheet) to bootstrap? Also I added a navbar with a toggle button. I coded it to have icon bar for each link in the navbar. But the toggle button is only a square button and it's not aligned right like I thought it would be. Could someone help me out?

I've figured out my toggle button issue. I just want to understand the concept of the collasping columns and how to customize that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

        <style>

            .box {

                background-color: #d3d3d3;
                border: 1px solid grey;

            }

        </style>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-default">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">

                <a href="" class="navbar-brand">My Website</a>

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button>

            </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                        <li class="active"><a href="">Page 1</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="">Page 2</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="">Page 3</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="">Page 4</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="">Page 5</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="">Page 6</a></li>                  
                    </ul>


                </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <div class="container">

        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

            <div class="form-group">

            <label for="email">Email Address</label>

            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email" />


            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="password">Password</label>

                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password"

            </div><br>

                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Login" />

            </form><br><br>

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">

                <tr class="success">

                    <th>

                        Name

                    </th>

                    <th>

                        Age

                    </th>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td class="danger">

                        Rob

                    </td>

                    <td>

                        33
                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>

                    Jenny

                    </td>

                    <td>

                    35

                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>

                        Rob

                    </td>

                    <td>

                        33

                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>

                        Jenny

                    </td>

                    <td>

                        35
                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>

                        Rob

                    </td>

                    <td>

                        33

                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>

                        Jenny

                    </td>

                    <td>

                        35

                    </td>

                </tr>

            </table>

        </div>  


        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4 box">Content</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 box">Content</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 box">Content</div>

        </div>



    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://developmenttesting.netne.net/bootstrap/bootstapnavbar.html

Answer (score 0):

*How does bootstrap know to stack columns at a certain screen size when I didn't put it in the code?*

It's in the Bootstrap code. Bootstrap uses CSS media queries to apply specific CSS properties and rules based on common screen widths (or "breakpoints"): http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

*Is this just a part of the link rel (stylesheet) to bootstap?*

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to checkout the [breakpoint feature](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) that regulates how bootstrap's grid systems adapts to different screen sizes;

if you need to change how the default Bootstrap is set up you'll also need to download a copy of CSS and modify it (instead of CDN),

there's also a configurator tha can make a modified stylesheet with breakpoints you set plus other customization goodies, [check it out](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables)!!

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed. I think I'm starting to understand this stuff.

Comment: I also suggest you look into the scss version for Bootstrap's stylesheet (it's mantained on Github)

Answer (score 0):

I will advice you to try remove links like:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and see what happens. Comment out some stuff and see what happens. The online courses I took too jumped most of it and that's the only way I learnt.   To understand more about bootstrap, you can read the documentation [bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/) to get more understanding of the whole thing but the best way is to try stuff you will read or see during the course, it will really help you get a grasp. Goodluck with your course